# label.setToolTipText("<html><p width=\"350\">" + text.toUpperCase() + "</p></html>") in java SWT not working

Tags: java, tooltip, swt

I want to display my tooltip in multiple lines when it crosse max width for ex: 350 characters.

```
Label label = new Label(this.wfSummaryComposite, SWT.NONE);
String text = "Text which has more than 350 characters"
label.setToolTipText("<html><p width=\"350\">" + text.toUpperCase() + "</p></html>")
```

I added this code but it not working.

Comment: Swing and SWT are complete different GUIs, this can't be both

Comment: setToolTipText does not support HTML

Comment: is there any way I can do it in swt?

Comment: If you can use JFace you can extend the `org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip` or `org.eclipse.jface.window.DefaultToolTip` classes . If you want SWT only look at `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolTip`. None if these do HTML but can be made to wrap text.